# Graphics driver problem: GTX 1050 - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver

I have a problem installing graphics drivers for Nvidia GTX 1050 on my Dell XPS 15 9560 running Ubuntu 18.04.

**My Problem:**

When I installed the drivers for my graphics card in Linux and reboot, i just boot up into a black screen saying:

"/dev/sdb2: clean, 185450/31244288 files, 4166820/124957440 blocks"

From this "black screen" I can go into TTY.

**What I have tried:**

I have searched the web and tried the following

- Turn secure-boot off.
- Tried several different drivers.
- Tried formatting the SSD and reinstalling Ubuntu.

**An answer would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to switch back to the Nvidia proprietary driver after switching to the open source driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274939/unable-to-switch-back-to-the-nvidia-proprietary-driver-after-switching-to-the-op)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and returned back to using the default xorg-xserver this has the down-side that the laptop screen is slow in response and the HDMI port and brightness settings do not work anymore... At least I can use my laptop again. Going back to older kernel versions did not seem to help (some other update is also blocking the nvidia drivers from working properly). Also tried nvidia driver 410.

This happened just after installing the updates yesterday and now I am running kernel 4.15.0.38.

Answer (score 0):

I just fought through an upgrade from  16.04 to 18.04 on a PC with two older Nvidia graphics cards. I can't help you specifically, but take a look at these two config files, `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

This is my file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. Note the `WaylandEnable = false` option.

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=knb
#AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin=knb
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

This is my `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`,containing only one line:

`/usr/sbin/gdm3`