# Unable to switch back to the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver after switching to the open source driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, additional-drivers

It won't allow me to select anything in Additional Drivers which says: *The device is using a manually installed driver*.

[image]

I am unable to switch back to the Nvidia proprietary driver after switching to the open source driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove all the nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
2. If you have added an Nvidia PPA to `/etc/apt/sources.list` remove that PPA by prefacing its line in sources.list with a `#` to comment it out. Run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.
3. Reboot with `sudo reboot`
4. Run the following command to install the correct proprietary Nvidia driver.

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
   ```

   The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies. This would normally include the *nvidia-prime* package (tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime). Then you will have an Nvidia X Server Settings icon in the Dash, and there in the left pane of Nvidia X Server Settings you can find PRIME profiles.

Comment: After doing this my laptop would no longer boot. YMMV.

Comment: @AdeMiller If your laptop no longer boots, boot into [Recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/859640/) and uninstall the Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers with `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia' && sudo apt autoremove && sudo reboot`