# NVIDIA_SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDA driver (booting log)

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I show at booting log

"NVIDIA_SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDA river is installed and running."

It seems install wrong nvidia driver version.

It keep repeat booting below step

How can I uninstall NVIDIA-driver?
[booting error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5tBh.jpg)

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS? Also, are you able to get to the GRUB menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to switch back to the Nvidia proprietary driver after switching to the open source driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274939/unable-to-switch-back-to-the-nvidia-proprietary-driver-after-switching-to-the-op)