# nvidia driver version selection

Tags: drivers, nvidia, snap

I have a nvidia card, so I need its driver

[image]

In the image attached, it is shown as I can't select any nvidia proprietary driver version other than the one that is already installed

Is this because I removed snap ?

Do I need it back in order to be able to select a more apt nvidia driver version ?

Also, this is in the terminal

```
:~$ apt list --upgradable
Elencazione... Fatto
libnvidia-cfg1-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-compute-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-compute-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-decode-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-decode-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-encode-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-encode-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-extra-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-fbc1-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-fbc1-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-gl-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-gl-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libpq5/pgadmin4 15.1-1.pgdg22.04+1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
linux-modules-nvidia-510-server-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0-56.62+1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 5.15.0-56.62]
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-56-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0-56.62+1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 5.15.0-56.62]
nvidia-compute-utils-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
nvidia-driver-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
nvidia-kernel-common-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
nvidia-kernel-source-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
nvidia-utils-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [aggiornabile da: 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
```

a bunch of nvidia driver related packages seem to be "upgradable"

But then

```
:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze... Fatto
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto   
Calcolo dell'aggiornamento... Fatto
I seguenti pacchetti sono stati mantenuti alla versione attuale:
  libnvidia-cfg1-510-server libnvidia-compute-510-server libnvidia-compute-510-server:i386 libnvidia-decode-510-server libnvidia-decode-510-server:i386
  libnvidia-encode-510-server libnvidia-encode-510-server:i386 libnvidia-extra-510-server libnvidia-fbc1-510-server libnvidia-fbc1-510-server:i386 libnvidia-gl-510-server
  libnvidia-gl-510-server:i386 libpq5 linux-modules-nvidia-510-server-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-56-generic nvidia-compute-utils-510-server
  nvidia-driver-510-server nvidia-kernel-common-510-server nvidia-kernel-source-510-server nvidia-utils-510-server xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510-server
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 21 non aggiornati.
```

That says that the listed packages could have been upgraded but they weren't

With no word whatsoever as to why

Comment: why is this question being voted down ?

It's a genuine question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to switch back to the Nvidia proprietary driver after switching to the open source driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274939/unable-to-switch-back-to-the-nvidia-proprietary-driver-after-switching-to-the-op)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install them either through `Additional drivers` in `Software & Updates` or via the command line with the `ubuntu-drivers` command. I suggest to pick the one recommended by the system given by the command `$ ubuntu-drivers devices`

Comment: If you have a nVidia driver installed, you must purge to remove any old drivers before installing a new driver. Many older instruction have you adding ppa, that is not required as Ubuntu now has correct driver in its repository. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver & https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap

Comment: thank @oldfred the key was removing the previous installation before proceeding to install the new one