# sudo apt-get upgrade | error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, upgrade

**Declaration of problem**
Device HP Omen 15, Linux Ubuntu 22.04, GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile/Max Q

This Question differs from the similar questions with the same error due to the degree of overlapping driver files plus the risk of ruining my device as previously by messing with the graphics driver.

I am trying to perform the lines

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However upon perform the upgrade command I run into the duplicate error above and it cause my computer to crash and go into a black screen with the small flashing white underscore in the top left corner. I then need to hold down the power off to restart the device. I have looked inside the suspect folder and found many seeming close NVIDIA driver related deb files however I do not know whats safe to change keep to fix the issue at hand. I will attach the related contents of the file I believe to be the source of the problem below.

```
alex@alex-OMEN-Laptop-15-ek0xxx:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local$ ls
216F19BD.pub
cuda_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-216F19BD-keyring.gpg
cuda-cccl-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-command-line-tools-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-compat-12-2_535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
cuda-compiler-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-cudart-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-cudart-dev-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-cuobjdump-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-cupti-12-2_12.2.60-1_amd64.deb
cuda-cupti-dev-12-2_12.2.60-1_amd64.deb
cuda-cuxxfilt-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-demo-suite-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-documentation-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-driver-dev-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-drivers-535_535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
cuda-drivers_535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-535_535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
cuda-drivers-fabricmanager_535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
cuda-gdb-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-gdb-src-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-libraries-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-libraries-dev-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-minimal-build-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nsight-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nsight-compute-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nsight-systems-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvcc-12-2_12.2.91-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvdisasm-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvml-dev-12-2_12.2.81-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvprof-12-2_12.2.60-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvprune-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvrtc-12-2_12.2.91-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvrtc-dev-12-2_12.2.91-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvtx-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-nvvp-12-2_12.2.60-1_amd64.deb
cuda-opencl-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-opencl-dev-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-profiler-api-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-runtime-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-sanitizer-12-2_12.2.53-1_amd64.deb
cuda-toolkit-12_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-toolkit_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-toolkit-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-toolkit-12-2-config-common_12.2.53-1_all.deb
cuda-toolkit-12-config-common_12.2.53-1_all.deb
cuda-toolkit-config-common_12.2.53-1_all.deb
cuda-tools-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
cuda-visual-tools-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
gds-tools-12-2_1.7.0.149-1_amd64.deb
InRelease
libcublas-12-2_12.2.1.16-1_amd64.deb
libcublas-dev-12-2_12.2.1.16-1_amd64.deb
libcufft-12-2_11.0.8.15-1_amd64.deb
libcufft-dev-12-2_11.0.8.15-1_amd64.deb
libcufile-12-2_1.7.0.149-1_amd64.deb
libcufile-dev-12-2_1.7.0.149-1_amd64.deb
libcurand-12-2_10.3.3.53-1_amd64.deb
libcurand-dev-12-2_10.3.3.53-1_amd64.deb
libcusolver-12-2_11.5.0.53-1_amd64.deb
libcusolver-dev-12-2_11.5.0.53-1_amd64.deb
libcusparse-12-2_12.1.1.53-1_amd64.deb
libcusparse-dev-12-2_12.1.1.53-1_amd64.deb
libnpp-12-2_12.1.1.14-1_amd64.deb
libnpp-dev-12-2_12.1.1.14-1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-cfg1-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-cfg1-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-common-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_all.deb
libnvidia-common-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_all.deb
libnvidia-compute-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-compute-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-compute-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-compute-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-decode-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-decode-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-decode-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-decode-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-encode-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-encode-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-encode-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-encode-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-extra-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-extra-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-fbc1-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-fbc1-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-fbc1-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-fbc1-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-gl-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-gl-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-gl-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnvidia-gl-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libnvidia-nscq-535_535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
libnvjitlink-12-2_12.2.91-1_amd64.deb
libnvjitlink-dev-12-2_12.2.91-1_amd64.deb
libnvjpeg-12-2_12.1.1.14-1_amd64.deb
libnvjpeg-dev-12-2_12.1.1.14-1_amd64.deb
libxnvctrl0_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxnvctrl-dev_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Local.md5
Local.md5.gpg
nsight-compute-2023.2.0_2023.2.0.16-1_amd64.deb
nsight-systems-2023.2.3_2023.2.3.1001-1_amd64.deb
nvidia-compute-utils-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-compute-utils-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-dkms-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-dkms-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-driver-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-driver-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-fabricmanager-535_535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
nvidia-fabricmanager-dev-535_535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
nvidia-fs_2.16.1-1_amd64.deb
nvidia-fs-dkms_2.16.1-1_amd64.deb
nvidia-gds_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
nvidia-gds-12-2_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb
nvidia-headless-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-headless-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-kernel-common-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-kernel-open-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-kernel-source-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-kernel-source-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-modprobe_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-settings_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-utils-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nvidia-utils-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Packages
Packages.gz
Release
Release.gpg
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535_535.54.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

**Post question**

Is there a clean solution to fix this problem that's causing my device to crash?

I will attach a photo of the terminal moments before the crash below pardon the poor image quality it was hard to capture the almost instant crash.

[Terminal At Crash Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1G9d.png)

Comment: If you make a mistake with installing your Nvidia graphics driver you can remove all the Nvidia packages and then reinstall them automatically by following the instructions in the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1274939/).

Comment: @karel, Thanks for that! This resolved the issues cleanly