# how to clean up nvidia driver versions shown by `apt policy nvidia-driver-470`?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

(This is a follow up to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1501772/xorg-video-abi-24-but-it-is-not-installable-problem-when-running-sudo-apt-instal) question)

I think I messed up the system while trying to fix some issues. I tried to update Nvidia driver (the one that shows by `nvidia-smi`) and also installed several different CUDA toolkit versions (I should've used `.run` version instead of `deb`). I found that when I install CUDA toolkit from Nvidia website, it also changes the driver.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

Now I want to clean up some nvidia drivers but I don't know how to.

How do I clean up these versions shown under `Version table`?

```
    jun@hotcake:~$ apt policy nvidia-driver-470
    nvidia-driver-470:
      Installed: (none)
      Candidate: 470.223.02-0ubuntu1
      Version table:
         470.223.02-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
            500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
         470.199.02-1pop0~1702484215~22.04~b922bc0~dev 500
            500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
         470.199.02-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.182.03-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.161.03-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.141.10-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.141.03-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.129.06-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.103.01-0ubuntu2 500
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages
         470.103.01-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.82.01-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.57.02-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
         470.42.01-0ubuntu1 600
            600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
```

Adding some other info just in case it might help.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.223.02   Driver Version: 470.223.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:41:00.0  On |                  Off |
|  0%   39C    P8    15W / 480W |      0MiB / 24253MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
jun@hotcake:~$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
```

Comment: Look at "Installed: (none)". All the other lines are about versions that you ***can choose to*** install.

Comment: @DanielT That's a good point. I'll try. That might solve my original issues. Just to confirm, to install the second candidate, I should do `sudo aptitude install nvidia-driver-470=470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1` right? I don't want to mess up thigs.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to switch back to the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver after switching to the open source driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274939/unable-to-switch-back-to-the-nvidia-proprietary-graphics-driver-after-switching)